# How do I match this pattern using preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a simple quiz engine in PHP and supply the question text in this format

```
question|correct/feedback|wrong/feedback|wrong/feedback
```

There can be as many `wrong/feedback` options as necessary. I want to use `preg_match` to return the results so I can display them. For instance:

```
q|aaa/aaa|bbb/bbb|ccc/ccc
```

...should return...

```
array(
 0 => q|aaa/aaa|bbb/bbb|ccc/ccc
 1 => q
 2 => aaa/aaa
 3 => bbb/bbb
 4 => ccc/ccc
)
```

So, far I've got this regular expression which matches the `question` and the `correct/feedback` combination...

```
([^\|]+)\|([^\/]+\/[^\|$]+)
```

...but I have no idea how to match the remaining wrong/feedback strings

Comment: I see you have clear pattern for your data, I think `explode` will do the job `explode('|', 'q|aaa/aaa|bbb/bbb|ccc/ccc');`

Comment: Trying to use regular expressions to parse structures of arbitrary length or depth is not a good idea, because those structures are no longer regular. You can likely write an expression to match the whole `q|a/a|b/b|...` structure out of a larger input string, but as far as _parsing_ that structure goes you're going to want to write non-regex code for that. eg: `explode('|', $input);`

Comment: Thank you - I see that using explode would be a good option. I want also to check the syntax of the string is correct but I guess that the minimum 'correct' string is question with correct answer and feedback which I can match already.

Comment: You can do the checking with a regular expression. Just use a quantifier to match multiple repetitions of the pattern.

Comment: You can also use `preg_match_all()` to return all matches of a pattern. You can use that for the answers part.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar could you suggest a regex got me please? I've tried unsuccessfully. I want to a) check the syntax and extract the contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the "glue" feature in your pattern with `preg_match_all`, this way it's possible to check if the syntax is correct and to extract each part at the same time.

The glue feature ensures that each match follows immediately the previous match without gap. To do that I use the `A` global modifier (**A**nchored to the start of the string or the next position after the previous match).

```
$s = 'q|aaa/aaa|bbb/bbb|ccc/ccc';

$pat = '~ (?!\A) \| \K [^|/]+ / [^|/]+ (?: \z (*:END) )? | \A [^|/]+ ~Ax';

if ( preg_match_all($pat, $s, $m) && isset($m['MARK']) ) {
    $result = $m[0];
    print_r($result);
}
```

I use also a marker `(*:END)` to be sure that the end of the string is well reached despite of the pattern constraints. If this marker exists in the matches array, it's a proof that the syntax is correct. Advantage: you have to parse the string only once (you don't even need to check the whole string syntax in a lookahead assertion anchored at the start of the string).

[demo](https://3v4l.org/HrC7R)

If you want the whole question as first item in the result array, just write:

```
$result = array_merge([$s], $m[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after the advice, I've decided to use `preg_match` to check the syntax and then `explode` to split the string.

This regex seems to match the string format up until any mismatch occurs.

```
^[^\|/]+(?:\|[^\|/]+/[^\|/]+)+
```

If I check that the length of the match is the same as the original string I think this will tell me the syntax is correct. Does this sound feasible?

Comment: You don't need to escape `|` inside `[]`.